# Node version stuck in v6.13.1

Tags: node.js, anaconda

Looks like I have successfully installed the latest node, but how come my current version is still an old version?

```
 installing : node-v14.15.0
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/14.15.0
       fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.0/node-v14.15.0-darwin-x64.tar.xz
   installed : v14.15.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v6.13.1 at /opt/anaconda3/bin/node

(base) ➜  ~ node -v
v6.13.1
```

Comment: It told you that would happen, that's why it says `active : v6.13.1`.

Comment: They're installed in different locations. My guess is the old version is set in your PATH. If you ran /usr/local/bin/node -v it would give you v14

Comment: `/opt/anaconda3/bin/node` is probably a symlink. Try `cd -l /opt/anaconda3/bin/node` to see where it is pointing. If it is a symlink just delete it and create a new link pointing to the new node: `ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /opt/anaconda3/bin/node`